# Ubuntu 16 netboot (diskless) freeze in virtual console

Tags: 16.04, freeze, virtual-console

I've been using various versions of Ubuntu as diskless workstations (PXE boot) for a while (8.10 - 15.04), I'm actually a co-author of [this page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto).

Now I experience weird issue with Ubuntu 16.04. It hangs the system completely when I switch to virtual consoles (CTRL-ALT-Fx). There's no chance to SSH to it. It happens both when I upgrade from 15.04 to 16.04 or when I use clean installation.

- it does NOT happen on normal 'disk' installations where system is running from a hard disk. I can freely switch between GUI and virtual consoles.
- it does happen after the system boots and login manager is shown. I can sign-in, everything looks OK in X except for switching to virtual console or shutting down the system (it closes the GUI, switches to the console and freezes)

Hardware:

- Intel Core i5-4590
- integrated graphics
- 8GB RAM
- no disk

Comment: Is it possible that it's related to the fact that I'm booting the non-signed kernel when in diskless (netboot) mode? It worked fine when booted from harddisk, but perhaps it was using the signed version of the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it was all about setting kernel parameters. I tried upgrading the kernel to 4.7.4 but this didn't help.

It works if I set the following parameters:

video=uvsesafb:mode_option=1680x1050-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap,noedid

I'd prefer to not hardcode the screen resolution though.